# Why is the output of this program i=10?

Tags: java, object, inheritance, extends

```
class A 
{
    protected int i=10;
}
class B extends A
{
    protected int i=15;
}
public class Test extends B
{
    public static void main(String a[]) 
    {
        A obj=new Test();
        System.out.print("i="+obj.i);
    }
}
```

It's output is `i=10`, but how?

How is the memory allocation for the object will take place.

Comment: Because you declared it to be of type `A`

Comment: From The Java Programing Language 4th edition: "beyond being accessible within the class itself and to code within the same package (see Chapter 18), a protected member can also be accessed from a class through object references that are of at least the same type as the class - that is, references of the class's type or one its subtypes.". Section 3.5 - What `protected` Really Means - of the book goes into more detail if you are interested in knowing more. http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1051069

Comment: Because the declaration is of the class A, and you are accessing the var i directly, if you had a getI() in both classes for example, the result would be 15.

Answer (score 4):

```
A obj=new Test();
```

Means, you are accessing the members of Class `A` and executing the methods of `Test`(polymorphism).

I suggest you to read the official docs on inheritance and polymorphism to understand deep.

Answer (score 2):

*Polymorphism* is linked to *objects* not *references*. Since you are using a reference of type `A`, you will get `A.i` if you have method `getI()` in `A` and override it in `B`, then call `obj.getI()`, then you will get `B.i`'s value

Answer (score 0):

In java, Variable Overriding is not there. We have the concept of method Overriding.

In your code

```
A obj=new Test();
```

You can able to access members of `A`. If you have overridden same method in both the classes (Parent and Child). And you are calling that method with `obj`. This time you will get output from Child class overridden method. this is the concept of Polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

**Line 1: A a = new A();**

the method existence will be checked in A class and the method will be called from A class also.

```
a.g();//A class method will be called
 System.out.print("i="+a.i);//A class i will be accessed
```

**Line 2: A b = new B();**

the method existence will be checked in A class and the method will be called from B class.

```
b.g();//B class method will be called and it will also check that it is` available in A also or not if not then compile time error.
System.out.print("i="+b.i);//A class i will be accessed
```